# Missing Content-Type Header font-face with .otf

Tags: css, laravel, fonts

I use laravel framework. But in chrome console this error happening and `font-family` not working.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Missing Content-Type Header)

In css:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
  src: url(../fonts/HelveticaNeue.otf);
}
```

After searching I found that adding format() can solve problem. and I changed to this :

```
@font-face{
 font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
 src: url(../fonts/HelveticaNeue.otf) format(opentype);
}
```

Now error not showing in console but `font-family` still not working.

```
My file structure is: 
public
    css
    fonts
```

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at your log files, does it says anything? Try to load the resource with Chrome, if Laravel crashes and you're in debug mode you should see an error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't** get a 404 error for the asset, the issue is probably Chrome not liking the `.otf` font format.

You can generate a complete set of webfont types using the FontSquirrel Webfont generator: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

---

If you **do** get a 404 error you may need to add the necessary mimetypes for your server to be able to serve the fonts. Check out this little guide for how to enable this for apache or nginx:
https://github.com/fontello/fontello/wiki/How-to-setup-server-to-serve-fonts

---

Either way it's always worth having your `.ttf` and `.woff` fonts for cross browser compatibility, so definitely generate a complete font kit over at FontSquirrel.